# Beamer : Changing font size in notes when using \setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

Tags: beamer, fontsize, notes

I'm using Beamer with `\setbeameroption{show notes  on second screen}` to add notes for each slide. I'd like to change the font size of the text in the notes so I can fit more text on the page.

Clues?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define font size for notes with `\setbeamerfont{note page}{size=\tiny}`, default size is `\small`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be applied consistently in XeLaTeX, for subitems like `\note{\begin{itemize}\item thing \begin{itemize} \item subthing \end{itemize}\end{itemize}}`.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander I cannot help you with XeLaTeX, but I think `\tiny` is the smallest font size so I doubt about making subtiems smaller. A new or follow-up question could be a god solution.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander `\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\tiny}`

Comment: @bright-star This is the same with pdflatex. `\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\tiny}` changes the size of *all* subitems, not only for notes.

Answer (score 5):

Define the font size for notes as well as for subitems in notes with

```
\setbeamerfont{note page}{size=\tiny}
\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\tiny}}{}
```

as shown [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425060/52709).