# Changing fontsize on individual beamer note pages

Tags: beamer, fontsize, notes

I am writing a presentation in which certain slides are heavily commented upon and others not so much. As I am using `\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]` (and thus displaying notes on the same page as their relevant slide), certain notes are just cut off midway through. I have tried to find overlay options that would fix this, but to no avail. I think the easiest thing to do would be to set a smaller font for those pages with a lot of note text. Using `\setbeamerfont{note page}{size=\tiny}` — as recommended [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61647/beamer-changing-font-size-in-notes-when-using-setbeameroptionshow-notes-on-s) — doesn't yield the right result.

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Could you please post a Minimum Working Example showing your layout and the problem which people can compile to reproduce the problem? This makes it easier for people to help you and increases your chances of getting useful suggestions quickly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\tiny` in your note.

```
\note{\tiny Votre texte ici }
```