# Beamer notes page subitems too big

Tags: beamer

I would like to use a smaller font for my notes when displayed on a second screen. This can be done via `\setbeamerfont{note page}{size=\tiny}`. Unfortunately it does not affect subitems.  For example, here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\setbeamerfont{note page}{size=\tiny}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Slide Title}
  Slide text
  \note{This is small}
  \note[item]{This is small
  \begin{itemize}
    \item This is large
  \end{itemize}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When compiled the above document has a notes page with most of the text being tiny (as expected) except for the subitem ("This is large") which is larger.

How do I get subitems to inherit the `\tiny` font?

(Using beamer version 3.44.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\setbeamerfont{note page}{size=\tiny}

\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\tiny}}{}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Slide Title}
  Slide text
    \begin{itemize}
      \item This is large
      \begin{itemize}
      \item This
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \note{This is small}
  \note[item]{This is small
  \begin{itemize}
    \item This is large
  \end{itemize}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works! Is this expected behavior, or a bug in beamer?

Comment: @banbh I'd say normal behaviour. The font size of itemization is always independent of the normal font size in beamer. That it works for `\note[item]{This is small}` is more a lucky coincidence.

Comment: Also, if I use nested `itemize`s then I need to add `\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{size=\tiny}}{}`. This works, although I wonder if there is a better way ... (@samcarter ?)

Comment: @banbh I don't think there is a better way